# Post not working in my nodejs API to MongoDB Atlas with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

**IMPORTANT EDIT :**

There is nothing wrong with my code, the problem come from my connection, my network at work is blocking it I dont know why, I used my phone connection to figure it out. I'll look into it.

**Original message :**

I'm trying to make a NodeJS API using Express, Mongoose with a MongoDB Atlas database and my level with Javascript is like beginner / intermediate if you wonder.

I'm following this tutorial : https://youtu.be/vjf774RKrLc?t=2159 but he is using MLab instead of MongoAtlas and I tried to adapat my code to it.

So the passage I posted of the video is where I'm having troubles. His post is working but mine just does nothing and I get this error from PostMan "Could not get any response"

So when I try to do my post my `article.save()` is not working, and I dont know where I'm making an error. So there is my different files if you can look into it pls, there is not too much code for the moment so I'm posting the entire file.

app.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv/config');

//simplify us the use of json objects and encoded urls with special characters
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Import routes
const articlesRoute = require('./routes/articles.js');

//url redirections
// link to .../articles will be dealt with articlesRoute
app.use('/articles', articlesRoute);

//Home page of the API
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('We are at home!')
});

//database connection
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
    { dbName: 'test', useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    () => {
        console.log("Connected to db");
    }
);

//listening port
app.listen(3000);
```

articles.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Article = require('../models/Article');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('we are on articles');
});

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const article = new Article(req.body);

    try {
        console.log("try");
        console.log(article);
        const savedArticle = await article.save();
        console.log(savedArticle);
        res.json(savedArticle);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error :" + err)
        res.json({ message: err })
    };

});

module.exports = router;
```

Article.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ArticleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    reference: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    categorie: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    garantie: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Articles', ArticleSchema);
```

My 'article' object has the data but nothing happens, PostMan just load for some minutes and then I get the message posted before.

I also tried to the fixes adviced by PostMan but it changes nothing.

Thanks for the upcomings answers.

**EDIT :**

Thanks to @SuleymanSah I can see that I have an error when I connect to my database :

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED there.Is.An.Ip.There at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14) name: 'MongoNetworkError', errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ], [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

But I dont understand why, If anyone has a solutions thx

Answer (score 2):

In dotenv docs, the require is like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Also can you connect mongoose like this, so that we can see if there is an error when connecting.

Can you try with these changes?

```
mongoose
.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { dbName: 'test', useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => console.log("Connected to db"))
.catch(err => console.log(`Could not Connected to db ${process.env.DB_CONNECTION} `, err));
```

EDIT:

console.log(err) showed a network error, so after fixing it, connection succeed, and the app worked.

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I did what you said and now I can see I have an error trying to connect to the server :
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED there.Is.An.Ip.There
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

Comment: do you have a mongo db url in your .env file?

Comment: @oskll  can you console.log(process.env.DB_CONNECTION) before connecting to the mongoose? and check if there is a mongodb url there?

Comment: In your main folder there must be an .env file with content something like this:
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb://.....

Comment: yes there is the url provided from MongoDb atlas for the connection when I console.log() it

Comment: @oskll Did you added your IP to the white list in mongodb atlass?

Comment: @oskll it seems your connection is refused, please add your IP as described here: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: Yes I did add it

Comment: @oskll Did you before or now? If you did now can you try again?

Comment: I did it before when I was creating my database so since the begining, I checked again and even opened it to every ips and still not working

Comment: @oskll did you correctly copy paste your mongodb url from mongodb atlas and replace your username and username?

Comment: yes the url is correct and I did replace the username and the password

Comment: @oskll can you try removing useNewUrlParser: true  option and retry?

Comment: when i remove it it's worse than before, its needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201030/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-oskll).

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should try to check the network access in the mongo db atlas. And change the IP white list to allow from anywhere.